# Symbolic Function In Sage

Tags: sage

I want define a symbolic function

```
var('x')
f(x)=(x+1)%8
```

but I get the follow error

```
TypeError: unable to convert x (=x) to an integer
```

How I will be able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have symbolic modulo in that sense.  Indeed,

```
sage: x%2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: unable to convert x (=x) to an integer
```

`sage: mod(x+1,8)` gives a similar error, for similar reasons.

You can make a Python function, of course.

```
sage: def f(x):
....:     return (x+1)%8
....: 
sage: f(55)
0
sage: f(56)
1
sage: f(57)
2
```

If we knew what you wanted to *do* with your function, it might be possible to find a workaround.  I'm assuming you don't want to take the derivative, and that you only want integer inputs, so it's not clear that a "symbolic" version would even be appropriate.